# I can't backup mongo with mongodump and cronjob

Tags: cron, mongodb

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/mongodump -d mydbname -o /home/ubuntu/backup/`date +"%Y%m%d"`
```

Anything wrong for this cronjob? What can I do and check? I can run with correct result, tried with root and normal user:

```
/usr/bin/mongodump -d mydbname -o /home/ubuntu/backup/`date +"%Y%m%d"`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the command into shell script and set the cronjob to run that shell script but not mongodump command